# Node.js: How does process.env differ from global?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How is setting an environment variable like `process.env.thing = 42` different from creating a global variable like `global.thing = 42`?

When would prefer `process.env.thing` over `global`? What are the pros/cons of both objects?

Comment: Both `process` and `globals` are globally accessible variables in node.  Attaching `thing` to either just means that `thing` is attached to different objects.  Can you clarify your question a little?  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: As you say one is an environment variable and the other is set by your program. With process.env you can read the variables set in the system's environmnet. For example... THING=42 node server.js

Answer (score 10):

`global` is the global object. `process` is available globally, because it is a property of `global`. In fact:

```
global.process === process //-> true
```

`process.env` has properties set to the environment variables of the system.  These can be set a variety of ways outside of node itself, and read in by accessing properties of `process.env`.

At the command line try:

```
FOO=bar node -e "process.env.FOO"
```

The process module is just a globally available thing.

Answer (score 4):

The choice in my opinion must be something like this.
1)If the variable depends on the environment it must be set in process.env
2)If the variable is just a constant that is accessible from the entire application it must be set to global.

I think if you don't face these 2 points you don't have a need to store some value in both

Answer (score 1):

If you start your node.js application you may want to use some different "environments", like API-URLs and stuff like this, because in a production / live environment those URLs are usually different in comparision to your local development environment.

This means that you can inject those paths using a `.env` file for example BEFORE starting your application.

This is an example:

```
NODE_API_URL=https://myApi.com/myEndpoints myApp.js
```

The `global.thing = bla` line will be read **after** the environment variables were set.

Once the application is running the environment variables and the other global definitions can be accessed by the app.

Answer (score 0):

from the docs [NodeAPI](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

> The process object is a global that provides information about, and
>   control over, the current Node.js process. As a global, it is always
>   available to Node.js applications without using require().

You want to attach your environment variables to this object to make sure that there is no other pollution of globals.