# Cannot access properties of process when using it in object value

Tags: node.js, typescript, process, backend, development-environment

I am trying to use process.env in value of a key in ts. But I am not able to access process properties and its showing "Cannot find namespace 'prcoess'".

```
const MAIL_SETTINGS: {
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: prcoess.env.MAIL_EMAIL,
      pass: prcoess.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
    },
  }
```

i tried to make process as a global variable and used it in value but didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is typo in your code. Also, a technical aspect regarding import is missing. Like this.

```
require('dotenv').config() // requiring dotenv module
console.log(process.env)  // logging on screen to confirm

const MAIL_SETTINGS: {
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
  user: process.env.MAIL_EMAIL,   // use process.env
  pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
},
```

}

Also, for the .env file. It should be structured like this.

```
MAIL_EMAIL=test@test.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=test
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You had a typo `prcoess` => `process`
2. Not sure how your `envs` were loaded, it could be provided either via `dotenv` or other mechanisms. [Why dotenv is unnecessary](https://medium.com/ulangi-app/why-dotenv-is-unnecessary-4ca981c1253)
3. `process` is already a global variable, thus there seems no need to declare it again.  If interested, please see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861964/node-js-how-does-process-env-differ-from-global).